# how to properly implement conditional rendering for transform: rotate in styled components?

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components

I need to make my icon translated over activeColorColor prop, so it it upside down(180deg). My question is hwo can I properly implement this with condiionals witin styled components?
I tried sth like this:

```
transform:rotate: ${({ activeColor, color }) =>
    (activeColor === "(360deg)" && "(360deg)") ||
    (color === "(180deg)" && "(180deg)")};
`
```

but it is totally not working.
Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Emilia

Comment: There's a syntax error. It should be `transform: rotate()` format without any `:` after `rotate` CSS function. Also, I don't understand what the conditional statements are for. Assuming `activeColor` and `color` are string values for CSS color, it will never return `true` if comparing to `360deg` or `180deg`. What are you trying to accomplish here? What are the potential color values, and how they determine the rotation?

Comment: based on the ,,Active color" which I want to be my icon upside Down, so when there is active color it changes the color and its position to 180deg. When there is only color, I would like to have it in the original position.

Comment: So, there will _always_ be a `color` value, but `activeColor` can only _optionally_ exist. Then you want to rotate by `180deg` _only when_ `activeColor` exists, and otherwise keep it as-is. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: yes, that's correct. So far, I managed to do sth like this:                           ${({ activeColor, color }) =>
    color === "white" &&
    activeColor === "primary" &&
    css`
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    `}
  ${({ activeColor, color }) =>
    color === "black" &&
    activeColor === "neutrals" &&
    css`
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    `} .                                 Basically it works, but I think this is not the best solution ? I will have always defined two : color and ActiveColor this is why I put two of them.

Comment: Too many variables and too many comparisons only make it confusing. If the `transform` only occurs when `activeColor` exists, there's no reason to compare anything else. Conceptually it's like "if `activeColor` exists, apply `transform: rotate()`; otherwise, do not set `transform`." Even if `color` is dependent on `activeColor`, it shouldn't matter because you're only interested in tracking `active` state. Without seeing fuller code snippet, I won't be able to assist too much further.

Comment: Also, speaking of states, if your `activeColor` changes based on some kind of a state value, consider using the state variable directly to determine the `transform` value. E.g. if `activeColor` depends on a variable like `isActive`, it can directly be used for styling purposes, which makes it much more readable and easier to reason with.